# shared_ptr: Does the reference count increase when copying in a shared_ptr of the base class?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, c++98

The [documentation of boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) says:

> `shared_ptr<T>` can be implicitly converted to `shared_ptr<U>` whenever `T*`
>   can be implicitly converted to U*. In particular, `shared_ptr<T>` is
>   implicitly convertible to `shared_ptr<T const>`, to `shared_ptr<U>` where
>   `U` is an accessible base of `T`, and to `shared_ptr<void>`.

But I didn't find anywhere written if, in doing so, it will increment the reference counter.

I tried the following code, and [it works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10783034dd23c779):

```
struct A {
    virtual int foo() {return 0;}
};

struct B : public A {
    int foo() {return 1;}
};

int main() {
    boost::shared_ptr<A> a;
    {
        boost::shared_ptr<B> b(new B());
        a = b;
    }

    std::cout << a->foo() << std::endl; ///Prints 1
}
```

So assume this is always the case, but I couldn't find an information source that would confirm this.

Comment: Are you asking whether `boost::shared_ptr` has a bug?

Comment: @juanchopanza No no no, maybe the documentation as a bug :), but in fact no (I could already answer my own question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, when I finished writing the question I finally found the answer, in the [copy constructor documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#copy_constructor)

> ```
> shared_ptr(shared_ptr const & r); // never throws
> template<class Y> shared_ptr(shared_ptr<Y> const & r); // never throws
> ```
>
> Requires: Y* should be convertible to T*.
>
> Effects: If r is empty, constructs an empty shared_ptr;
>           otherwise, **constructs a shared_ptr that shares ownership with r**.
>
> Postconditions: `get() == r.get()` && **`use_count() == r.use_count()`**.

So, the answer is **YES**.